# Using "restart-computer" Cmdlet for remote computers using SSH

Tags: ssh, powershell, reboot, remote-connection, powershell-7.0

I want to reboot several computers remotely using PowerShell and wait until the reboot is completed, before continuing the script. I've stumbled across the "restart-computer" cmdlet and its "wait" switch parameter. Sadly, it seems like it's only usable with WinRM as the remoting protocol and not with SSH. We want to only use SSH for remote connections with PowerShell going forward and stop using WinRM altogether.

Is there a possibility I can implement the same functionality but with SSH as the protocol?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What if you tunnel WinRM through SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is that powershell can just invoke the built-in `ssh.exe` like other shells would:

```
# restart remote server over SSH:
ssh.exe user@hostname shutdown -r -t 0
```

---

A longer answer is that powershell 6+ can use the SSH protocol to establish remote powershell sessions, which have some more features than plain SSH. See [PowerShell remoting over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell) for details, but the basics are:

- Powershell 6+ must be installed on both the local and remote systems
- On the remote server, an SSH subsystem for powershell should be running
- Commands that use PS Remoting like `Invoke-Command` can use this directly by specifying `-HostName` instead of `-ComputerName`.
- Requirements are the same for linux and windows clients/servers (in case you're running powershell on linux)

When it's configured properly, you can restart a remote server using SSH like:

```sh
Invoke-Command -HostName MyServer -UserName MyUser -ScriptBlock {Restart-Computer}
```

and manually check for the remote server to come back up like:

```
Sleep 30  ## wait before checking
$SSH=$null
While(-not $SSH){
  Try  {$SSH = New-PSSession -HostName 'MyServer' -ea Stop}
  Catch{Write-Host 'Waiting for reboot...'}
  sleep 10
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I didn't work on this problem for the last two months this is why I'm answering this late. I know about the method of using "invoke-command" with ssh in powershell 7, but the issue I have there is that the script is not gonna wait for the restart to be completed. It's gonna execute it remotely on the machine, then the connection will be lost and the script will continue. "restart-computer -wait" will only continue to the next line, once the reboot is completed and this is what I'd like to implement with ssh as the remoting protocoll.

Comment: @Jellyfish Unfortunately, `Restart-Computer -Wait` only uses WSMan to determine if a computer is finished rebooting. If you want to automatically resume using SSH, you'll have to add something to try reconnecting until it's back up. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: thats too bad. Hopefully this will be added to the command one day. But thanks for the example, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Jellyfish yep it would be a good addition. If it helps resolve the issue, consider marking this as the answer, thanks!